# Simple π(x) in Haskell vs C++

Tags: c++, performance, haskell

I'm learning Haskell. My interest is to use it for personal computer experimentation. Right now, I'm trying to see how fast Haskell can get. Many claim parity with C(++), and if that is true, I would be very happy (I should note that I will be using Haskell whether or not it's fast, but fast is still a good thing).

My test program implements π(x) with a very simple algorithm: Primes numbers add 1 to the result. Prime numbers have no integer divisors between 1 and √x. This is not an algorithm battle, this is purely for compiler performance.

Haskell seems to be about 6x slower on my computer, which is fine (still 100x faster than pure Python), but that could be just because I'm a Haskell newbie.

Now, my question: **How, without changing the algorithm, can I optimize the Haskell implementation? Is Haskell really on performance parity with C?**

Here is my `Haskell` code:

```hs
import System.Environment

-- a simple integer square root
isqrt :: Int -> Int
isqrt = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral

-- primality test        
prime :: Int -> Bool
prime x = null [x | q <- [3, 5..isqrt x], rem x q == 0]

main = do
  n <- fmap (read . head) getArgs
  print $ length $ filter prime (2:[3, 5..n])
```

Here is my `C++` code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

bool isPrime(int);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int primes = 10000, count = 0;
    if (argc > 1) {
        primes = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    if (isPrime(2)) {
        count++;
    }
    for (int i = 3; i <= primes; i+=2) {
        if (isPrime(i)){
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << count << endl;
    return 0;
}

bool isPrime(int x){
    for (int i = 2; i <= floor(sqrt(x)); i++) {
        if (x % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Did you compile your code with optimizations on?

Comment: `-O3` for `C++`. `-fllvm` for `Haskell`. I don't normally use LLVM, so I don't know about the optimization level(s) it uses.

Comment: You'll want to use `-O2` when compiling with GHC.  The LLVM bit shouldn't have much to do with it (not entirely sure, I've never used it being primarily a windows dev).

Comment: And you should do your performance measurements using a benchmarking tool like criterion for Haskell, for C there's probably a dozen decent ones available in the repos of whatever *Nix system you're running.

Comment: I'm just running the programs from the shell and writing down their `CPU` times. Is that not enough? (Remember, This is just a little tinkering by me).

Comment: @bheklilr using `-O2` (no change from `-O3` BTW), brings the time down to 3x slower.

Comment: It's good for an estimation, but if you want very good accuracy a profiler is much better.  They usually also break down the execution time by function or even line number so that you can pinpoint the bottlenecks

Comment: The first major difference in the two implementations is that your C++ code isn't constructing any linked lists, so it's not the same algorithm.

Comment: I just tested this on my compiuter, and the haskell version was faster than the C++ one (using -O2 -fllvm for haskell, g++ -O2 for C++): haskell took 3.00s, c++ 3.36

Comment: So you're comparing a functional programming system to an imperative one with explicit memory management, by running a program with no data structures or even any unpredictable branches. By the way, don't forget `-fprofile-generate` and `-fprofile-use`.

Comment: By the way, my eyes hurt when I see those sqrt/floor computations. To check if `q <= sqrt(x)` can be expressed `q*q <= x` So there you have it: one integer multiplication vs. several floaing point instructions.

Comment: @Ingo: ... of which one is totally unnecessary (i <= floor (sqrt (x)) if and only if i <= sqrt (x)), and one is very expensive. And once x ≥ 2^53, things will go wrong.

Comment: @gnasher729, the problem with Ingo's code is that it substitutes a huge number of multiplications for a single square root, which doesn't sound like a good plan to me, unless the CPU is able to perform them all for free, which is possible. What are you trying to say about it?

Answer (score 34):

Your Haskell version is constructing a lazy list in `prime` only to test if it is null. This seems to indeed be a bottle neck. The following version runs just as fast as the C++ version on my machine:

```
prime :: Int -> Bool
prime x = go 3
  where
    go q | q <= isqrt x = if rem x q == 0 then False else go (q+2)
    go _  = True
```

3.31s when compiled with -O2 vs. 3.18s for C++ with gcc 4.8 and -O3 for n=5000000.

Of course, 'guessing' where the program is slow to optimize it is not a very good approach. Fortunately, Haskell has good profiling tools on board.

Compiling and running with

```
$ ghc --make primes.hs -O2 -prof -auto-all -fforce-recomp && ./primes 5000000 +RTS -p
```

gives

```
# primes.prof
  Thu Feb 20 00:49 2014 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

     primes +RTS -p -RTS 5000000

  total time  =        5.71 secs   (5710 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
  total alloc = 259,580,976 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE MODULE  %time %alloc

prime.go    Main     96.4    0.0
main        Main      2.0   84.6
isqrt       Main      0.9   15.4

                                                      individual     inherited
COST CENTRE MODULE                  no.     entries  %time %alloc   %time %alloc

MAIN        MAIN                     45           0    0.0    0.0   100.0  100.0
 main       Main                     91           0    2.0   84.6   100.0  100.0
  prime     Main                     92     2500000    0.7    0.0    98.0   15.4
   prime.go Main                     93   326103491   96.4    0.0    97.3   15.4
    isqrt   Main                     95           0    0.9   15.4     0.9   15.4

--- >8 ---
```

which clearly shows that `prime` is where things get hot. For more information on profiling, I'll refer you to [Real World Haskell, Chap 25](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/profiling-and-optimization.html).

To really understand what is going on, you can look at (one of) GHC's intermediate languages *Core*, which will show you how the code looks like after optimization. Some good info is [at the Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/GHC). I would not recommend to do that unless necessary, but it is good to know that the possibility exists.

To your other questions:

1) How, without changing the algorithm, can I optimize the Haskell implementation?

Profile, and try to write inner loops so that they don't do any memory allocations and can be made strict by the compiler. Doing so can take some practice and experience.

2) Is Haskell really on performance parity with C?

That depends. GHC is amazing and can often optimize your program very well. If you know what you're doing you can usually get close to the performance of optimized C (100% - 200% of C's speed). That said, these optimizations are not always easy or pretty to the eye and high level Haskell can be slower. But don't forget that you're gaining amazing expressiveness and high level abstractions when using Haskell. It will usually be fast enough for all but the most performance critical applications and even then you can often get pretty close to C with some profiling and performance optimizations.

Comment: wow! Thanks for all of the information. (Esp. the profiling part). I did try a tail-recursive version, but it was really slow for some reason or other (I use multiple arguments to carry around variables). Is my C++ (4.8.2) just really fast? It's still a hair faster than 1.5x the speed of Haskell, though I'm pretty happy myself. I'm not giving up the expressiveness any time soon, I just wanted to see how much it hurt. :) I'll see if anyone else has anything to add... If not, yours is the accepted answer.

Comment: @PythonNut: If you run it with profiling enabled it will be slower of course. In my experience you can get pretty close (+50-100%), but parity can sometimes be hard / impossible to achieve. Depends on your experience, I am not the absolute expert here. 

What will stand between you and performance though is that these expressive languages can make it really tempting to use high level constructs that will not be as fast as a bare-bones loop. The lazy list is a case in point. Still, most of the time it doesn't matter and you're still getting good speed.

Comment: I think the issue with `prime` isn't the laziness as much as it is unboxing.  With @Paul's `prime`, ghc produces an unboxed inner loop.   With a lazy list the inner loop is very nice, but it works on boxed integers and therefore has to unbox them at each step.  Incidentally, I get the same performance as the recursive `prime` by changing the original `prime` definition to use unboxed vectors instead of lists.

Comment: Nope, I tested it without profiling (the increase in runtime was noticeable). I'm personally very happy about the whole thing.

Comment: @JohnL interesting observation. I guess a look at the Core would yield clarity, it's a bit late for me now ...

Comment: @PythonNut Ah, ok. Not sure what the issue is then. Performance can vary a bit across compiler versions and backends. I usually declare victory when I get into the 50% slower than C range though ;)

Comment: @JohnL, do you have the source for that? I'd like to know how to use unboxed arrays.

Comment: @PythonNut He's likely referring to unboxed vectors: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.9.1

Vectors are not as typical a choice in functional programming as they are in imperative programming though (difficulty with immutality).

Comment: @Paul: yes, I was using `Data.Vector.Unboxed` from that package.  Vectors are a very good choice (even in Haskell!) for many problems.  I no longer have the code I tested, but it was just re-writing `prime` using functions instead of a list comprehension, then converting to vectors was quite straightforward.  Due to stream fusion, no vector is actually constructed, instead the result is a simple loop.

Comment: `V.null $ V.filter (\q -> rem x q == 0) $ V.generate (isqrt x) $ (+3) . (2*)` (with `Data.Vector.Unboxed as V` is much slower. How is your method different (ie. what did do wrong here?)

Comment: Oops, fail `V.null $ V.filter (\q -> rem x q == 0) $ V.generate (div (isqrt x) 2) $ (+3) . (2*)` is better, but still about 2x slower than @paul's solution.

Comment: Did you try `V.null $ V.filter (\q -> rem x q == 0) $ V.iterateN (quot (isqrt x) 2) (+2) $ 3` instead ? seems you might win a little bit over `generate`.

Comment: And sometimes (this is a bit silly and unlikely but still sometimes true) using ($) can hinder optimization, so you could try `V.null . V.filter ((== 0) . (rem x)) . V.iterateN (isqrt x \`quot\` 2) (+2) $ 3` .

Comment: And `(isqrt x \`quot\` 2)` is in fact a bit too long, for instance for 36 is will include 7 in the test list. You can do better with : `V.null . V.filter ((== 0) . (rem x)) . V.enumFromStepN 3 2 $ ((isqrt x - 1) \`quot\` 2)`. I switched to enumFromStepN here and it seems to help without optimization at least... with -O2 I don't know.

Comment: Checking with Criterion, the version with iterateN and the right number of element is as fast as the loop so `V.null . V.filter ((== 0) . (rem x)) . V.iterateN ((isqrt x - 1) \`quot\` 2) (+2) $ 3` .

Answer (score 3):

I dont think that the Haskell version (original and improved by first answer) are equivalent with the C++ version.
The reason is this:
Both only consider every second element (in the prime function), while the C++ version scans every element (only i++ in the isPrime() function.

When i fix this (change i++ to i+=2 in the isPrime() function for C++) i get down to almost 1/3 of the runtime of the optimized Haskell version (2.1s C++ vs 6s Haskell).

The output remains the same for both (of course).
Note that this is no specific opimization of the C++ version ,just an adaptation of the trick already applied in the Haskell version.

Comment: Also i has to start from 3, same as in both Hasell versions.